# Mono vs CompletableFuture

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, completable-future

`CompletableFuture` executes a task on a separate thread ( uses a thread-pool ) and provides a callback function. Let's say I have an API call in a `CompletableFuture`. Is that an API call blocking? Would the thread be blocked till it does not get a response from the API? ( I know main thread/tomcat thread will be non-blocking, but what about the thread on which CompletableFuture task is executing? )

Mono is completely non-blocking, as far as I know.

Please shed some light on this and correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

## CompletableFuture is Async. But is it non-blocking?

One which is true about CompletableFuture is that it is truly async, it allows you to run your task asynchronously from the caller thread and the API such as `thenXXX` allows you to process the result when it becomes available. On the other hand, `CompletableFuture` is not always non-blocking. For example, when you run the following code, it will be executed asynchronously on the default `ForkJoinPool`:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }

    return 1;
});
```

It is clear that the `Thread` in `ForkJoinPool` that executes the task will be blocked eventually which means that we can't guarantee that the call will be non-blocking.

On the other hand, `CompletableFuture` exposes API which allows you to make it truly non-blocking.

For example, you can always do the following:

```
public CompletableFuture myNonBlockingHttpCall(Object someData) {
    var uncompletedFuture = new CompletableFuture(); // creates uncompleted future

    myAsyncHttpClient.execute(someData, (result, exception -> {
        if(exception != null) {
            uncompletedFuture.completeExceptionally(exception);
            return;
        }
        uncompletedFuture.complete(result);
    })

    return uncompletedFuture;
}
```

As you can see, the API of `CompletableFuture` future provides you with the `complete` and `completeExceptionally` methods that complete your execution whenever it is needed without blocking any thread.

## Mono vs CompletableFuture

In the previous section, we got an overview of CF behavior, but what is the central difference between CompletableFuture and Mono?

It worth to mention that we can do blocking Mono as well. No one prevents us from writing the following:

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }

    return 1;
})
```

Of course, once we subscribe to the future, the caller thread will be blocked. But we can always work around that by providing an additional `subscribeOn` operator. Nevertheless, the broader API of `Mono` is not the key feature.

In order to understand the main difference between `CompletableFuture` and `Mono`, lets back to previously mentioned `myNonBlockingHttpCall` method implementation.

```
public CompletableFuture myUpperLevelBusinessLogic() {
    var future = myNonBlockingHttpCall();

    // ... some code

    if (something) {
       // oh we don't really need anything, let's just throw an exception
       var errorFuture = new CompletableFuture();
       errorFuture.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());

       return errorFuture;
    }

   return future;
}
```

In the case of `CompletableFuture`, once the method is called, it will eagerly execute HTTP call to another service/resource. Even though we will not really need the result of the execution after verifying some pre/post conditions, it starts the execution, and additional CPU/DB-Connections/What-Ever-Machine-Resources will be allocated for this work.

In contrast, the `Mono` type is lazy by definition:

```
public Mono myNonBlockingHttpCallWithMono(Object someData) {
    return Mono.create(sink -> {
            myAsyncHttpClient.execute(someData, (result, exception -> {
                if(exception != null) {
                    sink.error(exception);
                    return;
                }
                sink.success(result);
            })
    });
} 

public Mono myUpperLevelBusinessLogic() {
    var mono = myNonBlockingHttpCallWithMono();

    // ... some code

    if (something) {
       // oh we don't really need anything, let's just throw an exception

       return Mono.error(new RuntimeException());
    }

   return mono;
}
```

In this case, nothing will happen until the final `mono` is subscribed. Thus, only when `Mono` returned by the `myNonBlockingHttpCallWithMono` method, will be subscribed, the logic provided to `Mono.create(Consumer)` will be executed.

And we can go even further. We can make our execution much lazier. As you might know, `Mono` extends `Publisher` from the Reactive Streams specification. The screaming feature of Reactive Streams is backpressure support. Thus, using the `Mono` API we can do execution only when the data is really needed, and our subscriber is ready to consume them:

```
Mono.create(sink -> {
    AtomicBoolean once = new AtomicBoolean();
    sink.onRequest(__ -> {
        if(!once.get() && once.compareAndSet(false, true) {
            myAsyncHttpClient.execute(someData, (result, exception -> {
                if(exception != null) {
                    sink.error(exception);
                    return;
                }
                sink.success(result);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In this example, we execute data only when subscriber called `Subscription#request` so by doing that it declared its readiness to receive data.

## Summary

- `CompletableFuture` is async and can be non-blocking
- `CompletableFuture` is eager. You can't postpone the execution. But you can cancel them (which is better than nothing)
- `Mono` is async/non-blocking and can easily execute any call on different `Thread` by composing the main `Mono` with different operators.
- `Mono` is truly lazy and allows postponing execution startup by the subscriber presence and its readiness to consume data.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, Oleh. Really appreciate it. That means my understanding was right : If I make an api call in CompletableFuture which takes 1 sec to respond, then the thread in ForkJoinPool will eventually be blocked for 1 sec? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @XYZ Underlying mechanism of ForkJoinPool is a little bit smarter, so in case of a high number of task, instead of blocking it can start doing another work in the fork, but once all work is done, it starts joining tasks and will be blocked eventually.

Comment: But as I said, it depends on the underlying implementation of the client.

Comment: Also, a ForkJoinTask *may* be executed on the current thread if the Task result is requested before the Task has been send off to an worker Thread. That means if you submit a task to the pool but call `get()` directly on the handle, there is a chance that the submitting thread executes the action

Answer (score 6):

Building up on Oleh's answer, a possible lazy solution for `CompletableFuture` would be

```java
public CompletableFuture myNonBlockingHttpCall(CompletableFuture<ExecutorService> dispatch, Object someData) {
    var uncompletedFuture = new CompletableFuture(); // creates uncompleted future

    dispatch.thenAccept(x -> x.submit(() -> {
        myAsyncHttpClient.execute(someData, (result, exception -> {
            if(exception != null) {
                uncompletedFuture.completeExceptionally(exception);
                return;
            }
            uncompletedFuture.complete(result);
        })
    }));

    return uncompletedFuture;
}
```

Then, later on you simply do

```java
dispatch.complete(executor);
```

That would make `CompletableFuture` equivalent to `Mono`, but without backpressure, I guess.